# Preview Image Dimensions

Tags: macos, preview

How can I quickly view the dimensions of an image that I have open in Preview?  Looking at the menu options, I'm not seeing an obvious choice, such as "properties", to see such info.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you want is Tools -> Show Inspector.

[image]

This will then display the inspector, with four tabs.  The first one is titled "General Info", and includes the dimensions in pixels next to the label "Image size".

[image]